# "Edited by" block is not updated after editing tags inline

Tags: bug, tags, edits, inline-tag-editor

- Go to a question that was already edited by someone else
- Press "edit tags", edit, "Save Tag Edits"
- => the "`edited <date> (<br>) <user>`" block in the center under the post still shows the previous editor and date

Comment: I just added the discussion tag to your question and it shows me as the editor ...

Comment: I've also tested on a previously edit question on [su](https://superuser.com/q/251713/337631) and cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: Can you link to the question where you *did* see this happen?

Comment: No repro for me either on [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/460767/revisions).

Comment: I have seen this too on SO. reloading the page fixes it.

Comment: @CrisLuengo The bug is exactly that the JS logic doesn't update it, you need to reload the page. (Anyway, ty for pointing out that it's specific to SO, I didn't notice that.)

Comment: @ivan it's not SO specific (I just reprod on this question), it's inline tag editing which is a 10k privilege